# get the backtrace before unwinding the stack

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, gdb

My process is not running on a debugger, instead it generates a core file when crash happened.
UPDATE: The crash happens due to an exception. From a throw() and it was not handled even in main() scope.

When I attach it and run it inside a debugger it does generate backtrace correctly but in the corefile it does not.

The issue may be operating system unwinds the stack before passing control to terminate so when terminate generates the SIGABT it does not have such information about the previous stack.

I'm getting this crash for a stress memory testing, so there's no way I could ru n this under gdb.

What to do ? Any walkaround

Answer (score 1):

> The issue may be operating system unwinds the stack before passing control to terminate

The Linux OS does no such thing.

You didn't supply relevant details, but the two most common causes for "bad" stack trace from a core dump are:

1. running out of `ulimit -c` and getting a truncated core dump, or
2. trying to analyse `core` using different system libraries from the ones used to produce it. This could happen if you produce and analyse `core` on different machines, or if you've upgraded system libraries in between.

Comment: No I have set those limits correctly. I set up ulimit to 'unlimited' and this is a daemon program so I have exported DAEMON_COREFILE_LIMIT also set to 'unlimited'. So corefile creates the directory which I've mentioned in /etc/sysctl.conf and it works fine. 

Sorry I forget to mention that this is happening when an exception is thrown/happened. In a case of an exception